# Nested fragments good practice?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

I wonder if it is good practice to use nested fragments. Consider, there is Activity. I need to place viewpager at the top of it and list view above viewpager.
It would be better to use two containers one for ViewPager, another for ListView, it is clear.
But the question is is good practice to use antoher fragment as container for two nested. I mean that this fragment will have to layouts for two nested fragments, it will have similiar layout file as activity if there are two fragments without parent one.
So I wonder is it good practice to use one main fragment in each activity which plays container role and store all other components inside this container fragment or it is better just use several fragments inside activity without container fragment. 
I would be grateful for any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "container" `Fragment` is not a good idea, simply because it will mean two layers of nested `Fragment`s: the outermost "container" `Fragment`, inside it the `Fragment` which holds the `ViewPager`, and the `ViewPager` itself which holds a set of `Fragments`.

It would be better to not have the "container" `Fragment` at all. Keep the rest same.